# How to install Oracle Java from the official website?

Tags: java, oracle

I want to install Oracle Java (JRE) from the [official website](http://java.com).And set it as default.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Java by adding the Oracle Java (JDK) 6 / 7 / 8 Installer PPA to your systems software sources.To add the PPA and install Oracle Java 8 open a terminal window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and copy+paste the following lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y    
sudo apt update && sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer -y
```

When Java is installed you can close the terminal window.

This is the easiest way i know to install java on Ubuntu.